# Thunderbird Need Bigger Thread Pane Font, But Boxing Still Too Small

Tags: macos, thunderbird, xulrunner

So I was trying to help a friend make the font bigger in [Thunderbird's thread pane](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Pane_and_menu_fonts).  I tried different variations of the following to `~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/*/chrome/userChrome.css` (it's on OS X obviously), but the problem is the text is just slightly too big for each entry in the thread pane, so letters like g, q, etc. get cut off at the bottom.  Obviously, the smaller default font does not have this issue.  Any help?

```
#threadTree treechildren:-moz-tree-row {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Lucinda Grande;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
}
```

Or this.

```
#threadTree treechildren:-moz-tree-row {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Lucinda Grande;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

Or this.

```
#threadTree treechildren:-moz-tree-row {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Lucinda Grande;
  /* margin-top: 5px !important; */
  /* margin-bottom: 5px !important; */
  height: 25px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting min-height a bit higher than the text font works for me:

My userChrome.css :

```
/* UI font for lists */
treechildren {font-size: 13pt; font-family: Lucida Grande;}

listitem, treechildren::-moz-tree-row {
  min-height: 15pt !important;
}
```